# How to create animation when select IconButton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have just created a simple selectable 2 `IconButton` as the below code:

```
class _RadioBtnSimState extends State<RadioBtnSim> {
  bool _isSelectedLeftButton = true;
  bool _isSelectedRightButton = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              Ink(
                height: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                width: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                  color: _isSelectedLeftButton
                      ? Colors.green.withOpacity(0.50)
                      : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.50),
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 40.0 : 30.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelectedLeftButton = true;
                      _isSelectedRightButton = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Sim 1',
                style: _isSelectedLeftButton
                    ? TextStyle(color: Colors.green)
                    : TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Ink(
                height: _isSelectedRightButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                width: _isSelectedRightButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                  color: _isSelectedRightButton
                      ? Colors.green.withOpacity(0.50)
                      : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.50),
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: _isSelectedRightButton ? 40.0 : 30.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelectedLeftButton = false;
                      _isSelectedRightButton = true;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Sim 2',
                style: _isSelectedRightButton
                    ? TextStyle(color: Colors.green)
                    : TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now all I need, I want to create a simple animation when select the `IconButton`...

Is there's simple and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for easy resizing and so many other animations you can use `animatedContainer` but if you want to use complex animations you have to use `animationController` and `animatedWidget`.

Comment: thanks for your answer I do not need make it complex I tried but it doesn't work could you tell me how can I use animatedContainer related to my code :)

Comment: instead of setting height and width of ```Ink``` just wrap it with ```AnimatedContainer``` and set it's height and width and give it a duration.

Comment: @MahmoudHarooney glad I could be of help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a AnimatedContainer with a box decoration. The color will animate automatically when changed.

Something like this:

```
var buttonColor = Colors.blue;

AnimatedContainer(
width: 100,
height: 100,
decoration: BoxDecoration(color: buttonColor,)
child: yourWidget
)
```

And then to change it:

```
SetState((){
buttonColor = Colors.red // or any other color
})
```

**EDIT**

In your case it would be something like this

```
class _RadioBtnSimState extends State<RadioBtnSim> {
  bool _isSelectedLeftButton = true;
  bool _isSelectedRightButton = false;
  

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              AnimatedContainer(
                height: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                width: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: _isSelectedLeftButton
                      ? Colors.green.withOpacity(0.50)
                      : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.50),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: 20.0),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 40.0 : 30.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelectedLeftButton = true;
                      _isSelectedRightButton = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Sim 1',
                style: _isSelectedLeftButton
                    ? TextStyle(color: Colors.green)
                    : TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20.0,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Ink(
                height: _isSelectedRightButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                width: _isSelectedRightButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                  color: _isSelectedRightButton
                      ? Colors.green.withOpacity(0.50)
                      : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.50),
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: _isSelectedRightButton ? 40.0 : 30.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelectedLeftButton = false;
                      _isSelectedRightButton = true;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Sim 2',
                style: _isSelectedRightButton
                    ? TextStyle(color: Colors.green)
                    : TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace both the Ink widgets with AnimatedContainer and give it a duration to it..

this way -

```
AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  height: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                  width: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 80.0 : 60.0,
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    color: _isSelectedLeftButton
                        ? Colors.green.withOpacity(0.50)
                        : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.50),
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    iconSize: _isSelectedLeftButton ? 40.0 : 30.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _isSelectedLeftButton = true;
                        _isSelectedRightButton = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```